# Insertion sort in Double Linked List c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, insertion-sort

I'm making a sorted double linked list using insertion sort and it seems I have a problem.
The given list is

> 50 20 60 40 30 100 80 70 90 10

and right below is part of the code that I made(`void InsertNode(int v)`), but the result comes out as `10 20 30 40 60 70 80 90 100 50`. 50 comes at the end of the list when it's supposed to be between 40 and 60. I'd really appreciate your help.

```
void InsertNode(int v){
    DblListNode *newNode=new DblListNode; 
    DblListNode *current, *previous;

    newNode->data=v;
    current=previous=first;

    while(current->right!=first){
        if(current->data<v){
            previous=current;
            current=current->right;
        }else break;
    }

    if(newNode==NULL){
        cout<<"No memory for newNode."<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    Insert(newNode, previous);
}



void Insert(DblListNode *p, DblListNode *x){
    p->left=x; 
    p->right=x->right;
    x->right->left=p;
    x->right=p;
}
```

Comment: You are not checking the first one.

Comment: Is it for learning purposes? Otherwise you have `std::list` and `std::sort`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your while loop to:

```
do{
    if(current->data<v){
        previous=current;
        current=current->right;
    }else break;
}while(current != first);
```

Otherwise, you never compare the value of of the element for which `current->right` is equal to `first` (i.e. the last element) to your value `v`.

Comment: It works perfectly now! Thank you so much. Now I understand why it didn't work well